# Why does the Station Inspector chase children who are on their own and threaten to send them to an Orphanage?

Tags: plot-explanation, hugo

In the Martin Scorsese film [*Hugo (2011)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0970179/), there is a scene when the Station Inspector catches a boy looking into someone's paper bag and then locks him in his office and rings to Police to send him to an Orphanage.

Is that what it was like back in the 1930s? Because today it's very different.